# How to host Flutter Webapp on a Subdomain?

Tags: flutter

Wanted to know the right step to hosting a flutter webapp on a subdomain. Purchased a domain on GoDaddy, wanted to host it on a subdomain: web._____.com

Also what's the best place to host the same when deploying on subdomain

Comment: I also need to seek the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

*flutter build web --web-renderer html --release*

Step 2: yourproject/build/web -- create a zip file from web folder content

Step 3: upload and extract on your subdomain folder.

Comment: I think this is the correct solution. We just need to compile it and upload the entire files inside build/web and provide a link to this subdomain from your main domain website. No need to use firebase deploy hosting. Firebase deploy hosting only works for main domain website.